# discord.js client.guilds.cache.get(role).members | Create a array with all members of a guild

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to create an array with every user with a specific role. But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined
```

The code that I am currently using:

```js
var role = receivedMessage.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "arole");
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(role);
if (guild == "") {
    console.log("guild not found");
} else {
    const Members = client.guilds.cache.get(role).members.cache.map(member => member.id);
}
```

Comment: Verify your guild id

Comment: i did but it still doesnt work

Comment: try to console.log(client.guild.cache.get("335507048017952771")) does it return anything?

Comment: it returns undefined

Comment: Mistyped change client.guild to client.guilds

Comment: use `client.guilds.cache.get("335507048017952771").members`

Comment: its client.guilds already and `client.guilds.cache.get(role).members` is undefined

Answer (score 1):

This code gets all members with a certain role in the server the message was sent in:

```js
const guild = receivedMessage.guild;
if (!guild) return console.log("Couldn't get the guild.");

const members = guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "arole")).map(member => member.id);
```

If you want to get all members with a certain role in a specific server, you can specify the guild ID:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(/* Guild ID */);
if (!guild) return console.log("Couldn't get the guild.");

const members = guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "arole")).map(member => member.id);
```

For more information on valid properties and methods, please read the [Discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).

Comment: members is still undefined

Comment: @tobi Where does `receivedMessage` come from?

Comment: `client.on('message', (receivedMessage) => {`

Comment: i just want the id. i get with the first line u send all the other informatuins nicknames ids etc. something like [0000000000, 000000000, 0000000000] or [Name1#1111, Name2#2222, Name3#3333]

Comment: Which `members`, the variable or the property?

Comment: this members `members.cache.`

Comment: @tobi Are you executing this in DMs by any chance? Also, what version of Discord.js are you using?

Comment: I use discord.js: "^12.2.0" and its not in DMs

Comment: @tobi I have added an error handler, but as far as I know, the code should work.

Comment: yes i have an error handler. I create a new bot and start from the beggining and check if its work

Comment: @tobi Please can you copy your code onto the site hastebin or pastebin and add a link here. Remember to remove any tokens.

Comment: i created a new file and pasted the code but sill doesnt work. [link](https://pastebin.com/MpJHi5rT)

Comment: @tobi You are trying to get a guild using a role, which doesn't make sense. Copy the top code block in my answer and ONLY change the role. Then it should work. For more information on valid properties and methods, please read the [Discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the guild is non-existent or your bot doesn't have acccess to it, you can simply check this by doing something like

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("335507048017952771");
if (!guild) return console.log("guild not found :(");

//also use the built-in array() method
console.log(guild.array());
```

Comment: guild.array() create this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined`

Comment: @tobi it looks like your bot can't fetch the guild, where does the ID come from? It has only access to guilds where it has been added as bot